# Finding a weighted sum of exponentially small terms that is bounded below by a polinomial

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I want to understand how I can make a sum of exponentially small quantities be bounded below by some polynomial. That is, how fast must a sequence of rates decay to $0$ in order to make it's sum bigger than some polynomial?

Formally:

> Can we find values $c(k)$ and $f(k)$ for $k \in \mathbb{N}$ such that
> $$\sum_{k=1}^\infty e^{-c(k)n}f(k)\geq n^{-\alpha}\quad \forall n\geq 1,$$
> for some $\alpha>0$, where $\sum_{k=1}^\infty f(k)\leq 1$ and $c(k)\geq 0$ for all values of $k$?

I believe I've found an example that works with $f(k) = c(k) = 2^{-k}$ (written below) but I'd like to know if it's possible to find better values for $c(k)$, for example $c(k) = k^{-a}$ for some constant $a$.

In fact, is there a standard approach to finding such things?

---

My attempt:

The slower $f(k)$ goes to $0$ the better for my estimates, so we take $f(k) = 2^{-k}$, giving us that $\sum_{k=1}^\infty f(k)=1.$
Now, suppose there's a constant $C$ such that $c(k)\geq C$ we'd find
$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{e^{-c(k)n}}{2^{k}}\leq \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{e^{-Cn}}{2^{k}} = e^{-Cn}$$

which is exponential in $n$. Therefore we must have $c(k)\to 0$ as $k \to \infty$.

As we need $c(k)\geq 0 \quad \forall k$ the first idea that comes to mind is either $c(k) = k^{-a}$ or $c(k) = a^{-k}$.

Now, to make calculations easy we make $c(k) = 2^{-k}$ and so we have the sequence $\left\{\frac{e^{\frac{n}{2^k}}}{2^k}\right\}_k$ which, for $k>N$ is monotone decreasing. (N depends on $n$ but that's not important).

---

Now, as we managed to find $c(k)$ such that $\frac{e^{-c(k)n}}{2^{k}}$ is monotone decreasing in $k$, we my compare the sum with an integral

$$\int_N^\infty \frac{e^{-2^{-k}n}}{2^k}dk\leq \sum_{k=N}^\infty \frac{e^{-2^{-k}n}}{2^k}\leq \frac{e^{-2^{-N}n}}{2^N}+\int_N^\infty \frac{e^{-2^{-k}n}}{2^k}dk$$

and so we just need to show that
$$\int_N^\infty \frac{e^{-n2^{-k}}}{2^k}dk$$ is bigger than some polynomial.

But we can calculate this integral simply by substitution $u = \frac{-n}{2^k}$, giving us
$$\int_{N}^\infty \frac{e^{-2^{-k}n}}{2^k} = \frac{1}{n \log(2)}\int_{\frac{-n}{2^{N}}}^0 e^u du = \frac{1-e^{-n2^{-N}}}{n \log(2)}$$

and we're done.

---

I didn't try to work with $c(k) = k^{-a}$ but it would be interesting to know if polynomial decay is enough. I don't think it is, but I don't know yet how to work with it.